# proving existence of TM that accepts the next language

Tags: turing-machines, reductions

I have an idea of how to approach the problem, but I'm not sure about it.
Given a Turing Machine, I can check how many states the machine has, and somehow by the number of states to know if the run uses endless cells of the tape.
However, I am not sure how I can use the number of states and what I should check.
What confuses me is that entering an endless loop does not necessarily require the use of endless cells of the film.

$L_k=\{<M>| \,M\,\,\,is\,\,a\,\,TM\,\,that\,\,uses\,\,at\,\,most\,\,k\,\,tape\,\,cells\,\,\,when\,\,\,running\,\,\,on\,\,\,\epsilon\}$

prove that:
$L^*=\bigcup\limits_{k\,\in\,\mathbb{N}} L_k\,\in\,\,\,RE\setminus R$

Comment: Is $k$ an absolute constant or is $L = \{ M : \exists k, M(\epsilon) \text{ uses at most $k$ tape cells} \}$? Do you just need to prove that there is a TM that **accepts** $L$? Or you want to **decide** $L$?

Comment: I updated what I wrote, I hope it's clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language $L^*$ consists of all Turing machines $M$ which either eventually halt or repeat a configuration. For each machine $M$, by simulating the machine you can easily observe that one of these possibilities has happened.

Comment: using infinite number of tape cells not considered an endless loop?

Comment: Thanks, changed to "repeat a configuration".

Comment: Is it always true that once a configuration is repeated, the Turing machine necessarily uses a finite number of cells?

Comment: Yes. I'll let you figure out why.